# Foursquase API - Get ALL Checkins of a user

Tags: foursquare

4SQ says it only accepts to get last 6 months or last 500 unique venues.

Is there a way to parse all the data?

I want to be able to analyze all the checkins of a user in order to draw some charts and stats.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the **venuehistory** service. 
I do it with **/users/checkins** and **/multi/multi** to batch my requests.

Eg :

```
/users/1234/checkins?offset=0&limit=250
/users/1234/checkins?offset=250&limit=250
...
```

If you store the checkins, you also can use the **afterTimestamp** param instead of refetching all the data:

```
/users/1234/checkins?offset=0&limit=250&afterTimestamp=lastCachedCheckin
```

If you need to have a "real time" freshness, you can use the **User Push API** : https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

Foursquare'll notify your server each time a user checkin somewhere.

Comment: So basically I can get all user check-ins! 
Great answer, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome ! Please mark this question as answered if you have resolved the issue :)